# Exact ODEs: problem with the integrating factor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

i am having trouble with this problem:

$$(y+x^4y^2) + x\frac{dy}{dx} = 0$$

From the context, its obvious i need to find an integrating factor. The problem is i can't seem to find a factor as a function of just y or a function of just x, and the whole thing becomes an enormous mess in no time.

Comment: an additional solution for this is $y=0$.

Answer (score 5):

$$xdy + ydx = -x^4y^2dx$$
$$\implies \frac{d(xy)}{(xy)^2} = -x^2dx$$
$$\frac{1}{xy}=\frac{x^3}{3} + c$$

The important step is to recognize $xdy+ydx$ as $d(xy)$. This way you don't need an explicit integrating factor.

Comment: that was great! is this technique a common one in exact equations or was this just a perfectly set up situation?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the "proper" theory of differential equations, but I this technique is a pretty common one which is quite useful.